# Connecting Workflow Manager with SharePoint 2019 error

Tags: sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-2019, workflow-manager-1.x

Current configuration:

- 1 SharePoint 2019 farm (single server installation)
- 3 Workflow Manager Servers
- Workflow Manager servers are load balanced
- Workflow Manager is set to work only on https
- Workflow Manager SSL certificate with DNS=*.domain.com & all 3 server names
- Required permissions are in place
- URLs (SharePoint web application/site and wfm) are accessible both ways

Running with farm admin account:
Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "https://siteurl" -WorkflowHostUri "https://wfmurl:12290/" -Force -Verbose 
Throws the following error:

Register-SPWorkflowService : Failed to query the OAuth S2S metadata endpoint at URI 'https://webappurl/_layouts/15/metadata/json/1'. Error details: 'There was an error deserializing
the object of type Microsoft.Workflow.Management.Security.OAuthS2SJsonMetadataDocument+JsonMetadataDocumentContract. Encountered unexpected character '<'.'. HTTP headers received from the server -
ActivityId: 6de1c881-b1ca-411d-9004-ceea397d4453. NodeId: SERVERNAME. Scope: /DEV. Client ActivityId : bdeb429f-7bb1-e0c1-d7d1-f868a175396b.
At line:1 char:1
+ Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite https://webappurl ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...WorkflowService:RegisterSPWorkflowService) [Register-SPWorkflowService], InvalidRequestException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it's related with post installing the April 2020 CU KB 4484292 and KB 4484291.

After call with MS premier field engineer it's resolved like http://thewindowsupdate.com/2020/06/04/sharepoint-2019-issue-with-sharepoint-2013-workflows-post-april-2020-cu/

You need to remove the existing SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer and the register it like below

1. Remove-SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer -Identity 9854855e-cea8-457f-8293-e405d4055ffb

(id from Get-SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer collection)

2. New-SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer -Name "00000005-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" -MetadataEndPoint 'http://server:12291/$System/$Metadata/json/1' -RegisteredIssuerName "00000005-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*"

or

New-SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer -Name "00000005-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" -MetadataEndPoint 'https://server:12290/$System/$Metadata/json/1' -RegisteredIssuerName "00000005-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*"

PS No any concern here at

Remove-SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer

easy to go

Answer (score 0):

thanks!
in the end, it looked like there were some issues with the F5 load balancing. As a test we added in the host files the URL of the WFM and the connection worked fine afterwards. this was handed over after to the team that managed the F5 and they resolved the issue on their end.